# Comparing lists items

Tags: prolog

I was wondering if you can help me in this Prolog program which should compare two lists' items and map them:
For example, I have got the two following lists:

```
A= [t1=v,[t2=w,[d3=a]],[d2=m,[d3=a]]]
B= [t11=v,t12=p,[t10=o,[t3=a,t22=w]],[t20=p,[t3=a,t22=m]]]
```

they are of the following (tentative) form:

```
is_plist([]).
is_plist([EL|ELs]) :-
   is_el(EL),
   is_plist(ELs).

is_el(_Name=_Value).
is_el(L) :-
   is_plist(L).
```

So, I want to compare them based on the values occur after the equal signs, since I have got similar values such as v, a, m, etc. So the output would be something like

```
t1 = v  ->  t11=v
[t2=w,[d3=a]]  ->  [t10=o,[t3=a,t22=w]]
[d2=m,[d3=a]]  ->  [t20=p,[t3=a,t22=m]]
```

This is because the first two items of both lists got (v). The second item in the second list has different value, so it should be ignored. The second item in the first list is going to be mapped to the third one in list B since they both have w and a, etc.

I tried to split the problem into sub-problems and got the rules for getting the list’s members and collecting text after the equal signs but stuck in the comparison part. Can anyone help me in this?

```
%getting lists members:
m(X,[X|_]).
m(X,[_|R]) :- m(X,R).

%Collecting text rules:
c([], L, L).
c([H | T], L0, L2) :-
  !,
  c(H, L0, L1),
  c(T, L1, L2).

c(_=C, L, [C | L]).
c(T, C) :-
  c(T, [], C).
```

Comment: Giving a name to the second predicate `([], L, L)` etc. would bring the program closer to syntactic correctness.

Comment: It is a nested list, where some items are lists. I dont want to flatten them.

Comment: @ally: Put a clean definition for your terms into your question. I added one suggestion which might be OK or not. But as long as you do not make this clear, other parts remain even more obscure.